# My Ajax calls are waiting for the first one to finish before it finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to build a tail like log viewer for my site using Ajax.. however for whatever reason, the ajax calls are waiting for the first one to finish before it completes the next call.

Looking at Firebug, both calls are fired off at the same time, however the second call (which only takes a couple of ms) sits there spinning and waiting for the first call to finish (which can take many seconds).

I am unsure why.. the first call that takes about 10 seconds looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url : "{{ url('json/import/run-import') }}",
  type : "POST",    
  data : formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success : function ( data ) {
    if ( data.success ) {       
    } else {              
      flashMessage(data.severity, data.message);
    }                                              
  },
  error : function() {  
    flashMessage("error", "An error occurred whilst running the import.");
  }
})
```

For the log viewer, I am using the following code: https://github.com/ukhas/js-logtail#readme

Is this a browser issue? I am using Apache on Windows (XAMPP) and Firefox.

Comment: This could be a server issue. Check the number of incoming connections it allows from a single IP.

Comment: Thanks..I was thinking it could be something like this. I know i've seem similar things before with multiple tabs open where it will only serve 1 tab at a time.